# Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a text box, and a button next to it. When you click the button, I want to convert to Fahrenheit or Celsius and display in another text box. I only have the Fahrenheit to Celsius done and I can just copy the code over when I am done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<center>
<h1> Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter</h1> 
<font size="+1" > 
<p> Fahrenheit to Celsius</p>
<input type="text" name="ftc" id="ftc"/> <button type="button" onclick="fahrenheitCelsius()" /> Click to Convert </button>
<p>Celsius to Fahrenheit </p>
<input type="text" name="ctf" id="ctf" /> <button type="button" onclick="celsiusFahrenheit()" /> Click to Convert </button>
<p> Answer </p>
<input type="text" name="answer box" id="answer/> 
<script>

 function fahrenheitCelsius() {  
    var fsc = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ftc').value);
    var cfc = (fsc-32) * (5/9);
    document.getElementById('answer box').value = cfc;
    return false; 
    document.writeIn(<input type="text" name="answer box" id="answer"/>)
    }

</script>
</font>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: The first thing to do would be to open the browser's error console and look at the error messages. You got quite a few syntax errors there.

Answer (score 1):

You made many mistakes. Here is working code for Fahrenheit to celcius: https://jsfiddle.net/nm8ashr1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>
<h1> Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter</h1> 
<h2> Fahrenheit to Celsius</h2>
<input type="text" name="ftc" id="ftc"/> <button type="button" onclick="fahrenheitCelsius()"> Click to Convert</button>
<p>Celsius to Fahrenheit </p>
<input type="text" name="ctf" id="ctf" /> <button type="button" onclick="celsiusFahrenheit()"> Click to Convert</button>
<p> Answer </p>
<input type="text" name="answer box" id="answer"/> 
<script>

 function fahrenheitCelsius() {  
    var fsc = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ftc').value);
    var cfc = (fsc-32) * (5/9);
    document.getElementById('answer').value = cfc;
    }

</script>
```